# Is it possible to use .dll files to link via applescript on mac?

Tags: javascript, ios, windows

I need to use .dll files on mac using applescript scripting language.

Is it possible to use this?

Thanks by 
John..

Comment: no it is not possible

Comment: .dll is a file extension specific to windows so you won't find native support on your mac. To obtain the same functionality you should look into OSX [frameworks and dylibs](http://superuser.com/a/228310/457117).